# Re-sample a signal with samples into all possible numbers of segments in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, signal-processing

Suppose, I have a signal with 10,000 samples in a single column vector like `[10000x1]` matrix

```
sig =    -0.1272
         -0.1124
         -0.1126
            .
            .
            .
```

and, I'd like to re-sample/segment with all possible numbers of sets with 1,000 samples per each. When I tried to apply random buffer function with Continuous Underlapping Buffers by using the code below:

```
new_sam = buffer(sig, 1000);
```

The result generated so far is `[1000x10]` matrix which is for only 10 random sets of 1,000 samples.

```
new_sam = -0.0374    0.0622   -0.0773    0.0655   -0.0410   -0.0859   -0.0647    0.0424   -0.0615   -0.0615
          -0.0820    0.0873   -0.0822    0.0105   -0.0060   -0.0659   -0.0948   -0.0277   -0.0814    0.0036
          -0.0666    0.0475   -0.0772    0.0855   -0.0260   -0.0610   -0.0848    0.0123   -0.1014    0.0186
             .         .         .          .         .         .          .        .        .         .
             .         .         .          .         .         .          .        .        .         .
```

The actual sample I'd like to get is all possible number sets (more than 500 or more N random sets with 1,000 samples each) such as `[1000 x N]`, but every 1,000 samples should be in order since they're signal values. However, each set should be randomized within a signal.

Answer (score 3):

Use randperm with sort:

```
M=10*1000;
K=1000;
N=10;

sig=100*randn(M,1,'single');

idxs=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)sort(randperm(M,K)),1:N,'Uniform',0)')';

sig_samp=sig(idxs);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, each of 1000 values in each random N sets, are not in order as they were in the signal, which makes corrupted signals in re-sampling each set.

Comment: The 'sort' makes them in order.